# Email when Taking a Topic using Google Groups Collaborative Inbox

Tags: email, google-groups

We use [Google Groups Collaborative Inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en) and would like it to email a member when they take a topic (when they assign it to themselves). At present it only emails when someone else assigns a topic to you (or when a new topic is raised which we have disabled for our purposes).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?